# Signals and Callback in gstreamer

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, gstreamer, video-processing

I have a question about the Signal and Callback functions.

The signal function:

```
/* Connect to the pad-added signal */
g_signal_connect (data.source, "pad-added", G_CALLBACK (pad_added_handler), &data);
```

The callback function:

```
static void pad_added_handler (GstElement *src, GstPad *new_pad, CustomData *data) {...}
```

I took it from the tutorials:

```
http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Basic+tutorial+3%3A+Dynamic+pipelines
```

My question is about the callback - How does it "know" the parameters ? It doesn't match the signals's parameters.

What is the `GstPad *new_pad` parameter? Where did it come from? Who sent it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can look this up from the api-docs:
http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/GstElement.html#GstElement-pad-added